# How to start an app iOS in background

Tags: ios, background, launch, beacon

I'm developing an app that listens the beacons, I want while app is in  background and is near a beacon want the app opens. How can it be done?
I can put the moment of opening in one of these two methods:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
   didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
 //..........
```

}

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
       didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
     //.........

}
```

Comment: @DavidH You should add that as an answer -- you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS can wake the app up in the background, the app can post a local notification, but there is no way for it to become the frontmost app and wake up the device. Notification can play a sound though, so you have some way to get the user's attention.

Comment: I have an iPad magazine that  he sends a notification with the screen locked, if I unlooked the screen I found the app open